# Azure cloud web apps slows load at start

Tags: azure, web-applications, cloud, azure-web-app-service

Not sure if you are experiencing the slowness of Azure cloud web apps loading at start even though AlwaysOn has been turned on.

Looking for any idea to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Riki

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer, thanks

Comment: Try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation

Comment: Jayendran, not sure whether the information is applicable to this situation. Only first time the application is slow, however once loaded, the application is extremely fast. I thought the Always-On feature which is pinging the site for every 5 minutes will solve the issue. But, it does not.

Answer (score -1):

As a workaround, we can create a Web Job that it will continue to call our web app according to a certain period, for example, every five minutes. By this way,our application pool is never unloaded and our site is always ready to serve users.

More information about Web JOB, we can refer to: [Run Background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs)

We can create a console application and upload it to Azure as our web job program. You can find how to do it with above documentation

**Update:**

As you said that you have turned on "Always-On", I guess the reason for this problem is the Recycling feature of IIS Application Pool.

We can disable it with this article: [Avoid automatic recycle of Azure Cloud Services Web Role](http://wp.sjkp.dk/windows-azure-websites-and-cloud-services-slow-on-first-request/)

Comment: Why is any of this needed? It's a first-time-visit edge case. And Always on takes care of the app pool.

Comment: Lee, thanks for the suggestion. However, the site is Azure cloud web apps and not an.azure cloud services web role

Comment: Riki, just to clarify, when you create a Cloud Service, Azure assigns it to a subdomain of cloudapp.net. Whereas Azure WebApps, assigns a subdomain of azurewebsites.net. 
Could you confirm if you have hosted your website on Azure Cloud Service or Azure WebApps?

Comment: Ajay, it is an Azure WebApps.